# FFT for a single frequency

Tags: java, fft

I need to get the amplitude of a signal at a certain frequency. 
I use FFTAnalysis function. But I get all spectrum. How can I modify this for get the amplitude of a signal at a certain frequency?

For example I have:

data = array of 1024 points;

If I use FFTAnalysis I get FFTdata array of 1024 points.

But I need only FFTdata[454] for instance ();

```
public static float[] FFTAnalysis(short[] AVal, int Nvl, int Nft) {
  double TwoPi = 6.283185307179586;
  int i, j, n, m, Mmax, Istp;
  double Tmpr, Tmpi, Wtmp, Theta;
  double Wpr, Wpi, Wr, Wi;
  double[] Tmvl;
  float[] FTvl;

  n = Nvl * 2; 
  Tmvl = new double[n];
  FTvl = new float[Nvl];
  for (i = 0; i < Nvl; i++) {
    j = i * 2; Tmvl[j] = 0; Tmvl[j+1] = AVal[i];
  }

  i = 1; j = 1;
  while (i < n) {
    if (j > i) {
      Tmpr = Tmvl[i]; Tmvl[i] = Tmvl[j]; Tmvl[j] = Tmpr;
      Tmpr = Tmvl[i+1]; Tmvl[i+1] = Tmvl[j+1]; Tmvl[j+1] = Tmpr;
    }
    i = i + 2; m = Nvl;
    while ((m >= 2) && (j > m)) {
      j = j - m; m = m >> 1;
    }
    j = j + m;
  }

  Mmax = 2;
  while (n > Mmax) {
    Theta = -TwoPi / Mmax; Wpi = Math.sin(Theta);
    Wtmp = Math.sin(Theta / 2); Wpr = Wtmp * Wtmp * 2;
    Istp = Mmax * 2; Wr = 1; Wi = 0; m = 1;

    while (m < Mmax) {
      i = m; m = m + 2; Tmpr = Wr; Tmpi = Wi;
      Wr = Wr - Tmpr * Wpr - Tmpi * Wpi;
      Wi = Wi + Tmpr * Wpi - Tmpi * Wpr;

      while (i < n) {
        j = i + Mmax;
        Tmpr = Wr * Tmvl[j] - Wi * Tmvl[j-1];
        Tmpi = Wi * Tmvl[j] + Wr * Tmvl[j-1];

        Tmvl[j] = Tmvl[i] - Tmpr; Tmvl[j-1] = Tmvl[i-1] - Tmpi;
        Tmvl[i] = Tmvl[i] + Tmpr; Tmvl[i-1] = Tmvl[i-1] + Tmpi;
        i = i + Istp;
      }
    }

    Mmax = Istp;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < Nft; i++) {
    j = i * 2; FTvl[Nft - i - 1] = (float) Math.sqrt((Tmvl[j]*Tmvl[j]) + (Tmvl[j+1]*Tmvl[j+1]));
  }
return FTvl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Goertzel algorithm (or filter) is similar to computing the magnitude for just 1 bin of an FFT.

The Goertzel algorithm is identical to 1 bin of an FFT, except for numerical artifacts, if the period of the frequency is an exact submultiple of your Goertzel filter's length.  Otherwise there are some added scalloping effects from a rectangular window of non-periodic-in-aperture size, and how that window relates to the phase of the input.

Multiplying by a complex sinusoid and taking the magnitude of the complex sum is also computationally similar to a Goertzel, except the Goertzel does not require separately calling (or looking up) a trig library function every point, as it usually includes a trig recursion at part of its algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You'd multiply a (complex) sine wave on the input data, and integrate the result.

Multiplying with a complex sine is equal to a frequency shift, you want to shift the target frequency down to 0 Hz. The integration is a low pass filtering step, with the bandwidth being the inverse of the sampling length.

You then end up with a complex number, which is the same number you would have found in the FFT bin for this frequency (because in essence this is what the FFT does).

Comment: FYI this is known as the [Goertzel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) - it's essentially just a single point DFT and is widely used for applications such as tone detection.

Answer (score 0):

The fast fourier transform (FFT) is a clever way of doing many discrete fourier transforms very quickly. As such, the FFT is designed for when one needs a lot of frequencies from the input. If you want just one frequency, the DFT is the way to go (as otherwise you're wasting resources).

The DFT is defined as:

[image: DFT]

So, in pseudocode:

```
samples = [#,#,#,#...]
FREQ = 440; // frequency to detect
PI = 3.14159;
E = 2.718;
DFT = 0i; // this is a complex number
for(int sampleNum=0; sampleNum<N; sampleNum++){
    DFT += samples[sampleNum] * E^( (-2*PI*1i*N) / N ); //Note that "i" here means imaginary
}
```

The resulting variable `DFT` will be a complex number representing the real and imaginary values of the chosen frequency.